# Is it possible to search a list full of tuples to find results after a certain entry in one of the tuples?

Tags: list, haskell

I am trying to search through my list of tuples and want to find a select set of tuples that come after a certain tuple containing a certain bit of data, for example in the following code i want to go through it and print all the tuples after "Someone Like you"

```
type Title = String
type Singer = [String]
type Year = Int
type Fan = String
type Fans = [Fan]

type Song = (Title, Signer, Year, Fans)

type Database = [Song]  

songDatabase :: Database
songDatabase = [("Wrapped up", ["Olly Murs"], 2014, ["Garry", "Dave", "Zoe", "Kevin", "Emma"]),
        ("Someone Like you", ["Adele"], 2011, ["Bill", "Jo", "Garry", "Kevin", "Olga", "Liz"]), 
("Drunk in Love", ["Beyonce", "Jay Z"], 2014, ["tom", "Lucy"])]
```

I think this would be done through list comprehension but I am new to Haskell and i am struggling to work out how to do it, if people could point me in the right direction that would be great!!

Answer (score 4):

You can use `dropWhile` to drop the elements before the tuple with "Someone like you". Since this returns the target tuple along with the rest of the list, you can then use `drop 1` to get rid of that tuple:

```
drop 1 $ dropWhile (\(title, _, _, _) -> title /= "Someone Like you") songDatabase
[("Drunk in Love",["Beyonce","Jay Z"],2014,["tom","Lucy"])]
```